# Whoops something went wrong error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, server

First of all sorry for this silly question I'm newbies , i got  this error when try to run a larvel project on my mamp apache server .

```
Whoops looks like something went wrong
```

I don't have installed laravel or composer on my  computer i was trying to run a project which i had get from my friend on my mamp apcahe server do i need to install laravel in order to run that project or i can just run it like other php script ?
And do i need to do anything on live server ??

Comment: You need to set the environment to development so that you can get the full error log. We can't help you just with this.

Comment: sorry but can u guide me how to set up ? i really have no idea how to get full error message sorry to bother you